# When I trigger custom event with parameters, parameters from event handler is undefined

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, custom-events

I've made a custom event using code below:

```js
function DataLoader() {
  let el = document.createElement('section');

  setTimeout(function() {
    el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('myevent', {
      number: 123
    }));
  }, 3000);

  return el;
}

// With code below I add my event listener.

let loader = new DataLoader();

loader.addEventListener('myevent', function(e) {
  console.log(e.number); // ← `e.number` is `undefined` when event is triggered.
});

document.body.appendChild(loader);
```

When the event is triggered, the variable `e.number` is `undefined`. What I've done wrong? I'm not using JQuery. [See this codepen](https://codepen.io/HPawelyn/pen/RVmmEv?editors=1011)

Comment: @Mr_Perfect: I'm following the guided in [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Creating_events)

Comment: Tell me what you want to do exactly?

Comment: @Mr_Perfect: If the event is triggered, the number `123` must been send to the handler to continue the process of initialization and that process needs the data that is loaded inside the `DataLoader` function.

Comment: To which element you want attach the event? Body or section?

Comment: @Mr_Perfect: To the `section`-element. my excuses if it is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create object `new DataLoader()` and declaring `let el`, the `el` is always undefined.

So you must assign some value to that. 
You must do something like this

```
function DataLoader(elem) {
    let el = elem;

    //When data is loaded {
        el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('myevent', { number: 123 }));
    //}

    return el;
}
```

and then create object like

```
loader = new DataLoader(document.body);
```

For more info [CustomEvent MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent)

Your code is unclear. Do like this based on your requirement.

```
var obj = document.createElement('section')
obj.addEventListener("cat", function(e) { console.log(e.detail)});

// create and dispatch the event
var event = new CustomEvent("cat", {
  detail: {
    hazcheeseburger: true
  }
});
obj.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: Oh this was an issue when I made my question. I've changed my code a it so it unclear what I'm making. But good point you're saying. I've updated my question.

Comment: I've found it too a shot time ago and indeed it's this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Send the arguments inside an object with key name "detail".

```
el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('myevent', { detail :{number: 123} }));
```

Refer - https://javascript.info/dispatch-events